# Open Source Projects Engineered using TDD and C#?

Tags: c#, open-source, tdd

I'm looking for an example of an open-source project that was engineered using Test Driven Development (TDD) in C# on the .NET Framework. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: It is interesting and exciting, but quite hard to follow. :)

Comment: I believe most OSS frameworks out there are heavily unit-tested. You could try to read the whole Castle Project that has a very high quality codebase.

Problem is usually that it's not that easy to get into those things since they are quite complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in web development in ASP.NET MVC (C#) check [KIGG Project](http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg) and [Kona](http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/) [Project](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/#MVCStorefrontStarterKit)

Answer (score 2):

Just doing Unit tests not means you are doing TDD.
TDD is writing test before the solution.

Comment: This seems to be responding to one of the comments on the question.  I could vote it up as a comment, but it doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) using TDD (as I do with all my code).

Answer (score 0):

Mono - http://mono-project.com/ got thousands of unit tests, can be useful to you.